# Problems setting dimensions of UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiscreen

The code below does as follows:

- detects width and height of screen
- sets the dimensions of the screen to a `UIImageView`
- sets position of the `UIImageView` to 0,0

Code (being run in `viewDidLoad`):

```
NSUInteger widthOfScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
NSUInteger heightOfScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
self.background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthOfScreen, heightOfScreen);
```

This is being tested in the Simulator on a iPhone 6.

When the code is run, the debugger says the dimension of the screen and `UIImageView` are 337x568 which is correct (When I implement the correct `NSLog` statements). But, the simulator shows a `UIImageView` that does not fit the screen properly. (It is too big). How can I get this to work?

I think it would be important to note that the original dimensions of the image being showed by the `UIImageView` are 768x1408.

Comment: Have you try clipping the UIImageView to subviews?

Comment: @faizmokhtar I'm not quite sure what that means, so the obvious answer is know. It sounds like your going to end up cutting the `UIImageView` into pieces, and I'd rather have one whole

Comment: Is  `self.background` the `UIImageView ` ? Did you use auto-layout ? If not, what is the `autoresizingMask` of the `UIImageView` ?.

Comment: Can you show more code. Where is this code snippet being run? Is it in viewDidLayoutSubviews? Are you running super first? Also, did you set the content mode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill?

Comment: @KudoCC Ya, I realized I didn't need that cause I'm not using constraints. Got rid of it. `background` is the `UIImageView`.

Comment: @Fogmeister It is being run in viewDidLoad, and this is basically the entire bit of code I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

http://tripletwollc.com/2013/02/resizing-a-uiimageview-in-viewdidloadviewdidappear/

According to that website, it seems as if you can't resize a `UIImageView` in viewDidLoad. It worked when I programmatically created the `UIImageView`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your image is too big and it is not clipping to the parent view. Try clipping the image first to fit the UIImageView.

`self.view.clipsToBounds = YES.`

You can refer about this from here:
[why is my UIView subview not rendering within the parent? (code attached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715341/why-is-my-uiview-subview-not-rendering-within-the-parent-code-attached)

Also some tips, try changing the background color of the UIImageView to red or something so that you can clearly how your view would pan out.

Comment: Didn't work. It doesn't even work when I set the parameters of the `CGRectMake` from a variable to just a number

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should push your code inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews` of your vc. If the problem is still, check the `contentMode` of your `imageView` and make sure to change it to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` if your image is too large.